# Why is the key truncated when using an MVC 5 WebAPI 2 Odata controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, odata

Visual Studio kindly generated the controller for me:

```
// GET: odata/Foos(5)
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<Foo> GetFoo([FromODataUri] string key)
```

But my key is of type string, so when I use the URL

```
http://localhost:46663/odata/Foos(46C1EF43FEF07176E04400144F1E6737)
```

and break in the controller, the key is only showing up as "46", which seems to be truncating the rest of the string.

What do I do? Using sane types for the key is out of the question, as it's an ancient Oracle database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, yeah, [here's the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026098/how-to-get-asp-net-web-api-and-odata-to-bind-a-string-value-as-a-key)

The answer is to use single quotes:

```
http://localhost:46663/odata/Foos('46C1EF43FEF07176E04400144F1E6737')
```