# ASP.Net OData with string keys

Tags: asp.net, odata

I am trying to use ASP.Net OData v4 (e.g. ODataController) to allow access where the key is a string. 95% of the examples out there use an integer as a key and the couple of posts I've found that discuss the steps to use a string as the key aren't working for me.

In all cases, I am trying to access my resource with the following URL:

/api/ContactTypes('Agency')

Optimistically, I started with just changing the type of the key from int to key:

```
public SingleResult<ContactType> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
```

But I get a 404 response. Changing the URL to an integer, /api/ContactTypes(1) does "work" in that it routes to the correct method and that the key is a string type, but obviously, that doesn't help me. This is the scenario described in this post: [How to get ASP.Net Web API and OData to bind a string value as a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026098/how-to-get-asp-net-web-api-and-odata-to-bind-a-string-value-as-a-key) except that that post implies that accessing the URL the way I am should work (and also is for OData v3).

After further searching, I found this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidhardin/2014/12/17/web-api-odata-v4-lessons-learned/ which basically says that you have to decorate the Get method with an explicit routing:

```
[ODataRoute("({key})")]
public SingleResult<ContactType> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
```

If I do that alone, though, I get "The path template '({key})' on the action 'Get' in controller 'ContactTypes' is not a valid OData path template. Empty segment encountered in request URL. Please make sure that a valid request URL is specified."

The comments in this post (https://damienbod.com/2014/06/16/web-api-and-odata-v4-crud-and-actions-part-3/) suggest that I need to decorate the Controller with an ODataRoutePrefix:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("ContactTypes")]
public class ContactTypesController : ODataController
```

That seems counter-intuitive since I do not have anything ASP.Net should be confusing. My controller name is already following convention and I have no Web API controllers that could be confusing it.

Regardless, it does seem to "fix" the issue in that the error goes away, but then I am right back at square one (e.g. only integer values can be passed in the URL).

What am I missing?

Full controller code:

```
[Authorize]
[ODataRoutePrefix("ContactTypes")]
public class ContactTypesController : ODataController
{
    PolicyContext _Db;

    public ContactTypesController(PolicyContext db)
    {
        if (db == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("db");

        this._Db = db;
    }

    public ContactTypesController() : this(new PolicyContext())
    {

    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _Db.Dispose();

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute()]
    public IQueryable<ContactType> Get(ODataQueryOptions options)
    {
        return _Db.ContactType;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("({key})")]
    public SingleResult<ContactType> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        IQueryable<ContactType> result = _Db.ContactType.Where(p => p.ContactTypeKey == key);

        return SingleResult.Create(result);
    }
```

Full WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        builder.EntitySet<ContactType>("ContactTypes");

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "api",
            model: builder.GetEdmModel()
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.If in your `EdmModel`, the string property is key, then no ODataRoute is need, for example:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

ConventionModelBuilder will use property named "Id" as the key, or you should specify it's a key like:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public string StringKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then the call like `localhost\api\Products('test')` should just go to

```
public SingleResult<Product> GetProduct([FromODataUri]string key)
```

2.If you already have a int as a key, but you want use string as another key, then you should try this feature: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-17-Alternate-Key , and you can call like: 
`localhost\api\Products(StringKey='test')`

Comment: Yeah, ok, so that was it. I actually had a property called ContactTypeId and also a property called ContactTypeKey (in our database, both are unique). The actual primary key on the table is ContactTypeId for performance reasons. I had to add the Key attribute to the ContactTypeKey property to get OData to recognize that should be used as the key for its purpose, but that confused the Entity Framework, so ended up also adding the following code to override the Key data annotation for its purpose: modelBuilder.Entity<ContactType>().HasKey(p => p.ContactTypeID)