# Swagger in ASP. NET Core OData interface with [FromOdataUri] params

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, swagger-ui

I've succesfully configured SwAgger for OData web API. All works fine for such actions like this:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
```

And route in Swagger UI looks like this: **odata/entities**

But I'm still don't know how to implement action like this:

```
        [HttpGet("{key}")]
        [EnableQuery]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
```

Correct route should be like this: **odata/entities(key)**

Actual route in swagger right now is: **odata/entities/{key}** and it doesn't work in swagger when you try to execute request

Please help to configure Swagger UI routes for OData in correct way

Comment: Can you share your model?

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005893/asp-net-odata-with-string-keys) may helpful.

Comment: I've added [key] but it doesn't helped

Comment: If an id of type int already exists in your model, then you need to add an alternate key.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger puts type of parameter as query instead of path. To solve this I used operation filter as below.

```
    public class SwaggerOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var parameters = operation.Parameters;
            if (parameters == null || parameters.Count == 0)
                return;

            foreach(var param in context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.Parameters)
            {
                foreach(var attr in ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerParameterDescriptor)param).ParameterInfo.CustomAttributes)
                {
                    if (attr.AttributeType == typeof(FromODataUriAttribute))
                    {
                        var routeParam = parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == param.Name);

                        if (routeParam != null && routeParam.In == ParameterLocation.Query)
                        {
                            routeParam.In = ParameterLocation.Path;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
    }
```